# mouseReleased() not called after adding component to a panel

Tags: java, mouseevent, panel

I'm implementing my own drag-and-drop functionality, and I've reduced my problem to this:

The code below works and will invoke mousePressed() and mouseReleased() as needed.
However, if you uncomment **frame.add(label)**, mouseReleased() is never called.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JLabel label = new JLabel("Click Me!");
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
        //frame.add(label);
    {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }
});

frame.add(label);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Why is mouseReleased() never called after the label is re-added to the frame's panel?

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: anyway why do you want to add same lable which is already exists ?

Comment: For my drag-and-drop functionality, I want to add the label in a new location in the same panel.